# Unmounting USB drive takes a lot of time

Tags: 20.04, usb, hard-drive, unmount

Whenever I transfer some data to my USB drive (even 200MB) and try unmounting it after the completion of the transfer. Ubuntu says `Writing data to a USB drive, the device should not be unplugged`, and then it takes at least 5 minutes to unmount the USB.

Things to keep in mind:-

1. This problem started a couple of weeks ago
2. I have tried this with 5-6 USB drives of SONY, HP, SanDisk. So, at least there is nothing wrong with my USB
3. Trying `sync` on terminal just hangs until the USB gets unmounted
4. My friend recently installed ubuntu and he is also having the same problem.

please help!, Is it wrong with my system or an update caused this problem?

Edit: My laptop: HP ay-542tu

Comment: (1) unlikely (2) Ok (3) that's expected (4) also expected but not a problem, a misunderstanding. What a file manager shows when doing that isn't the whole story. The file to be transferred is first buffered into RAM and then written to the USB flash; there are huge variations in write speed in flash memory and different types of USB connections but it's typically slow. The way other OS show progress for the same task may give the impression it's faster but if you actually time it then it isn't. Again, it's a problem of perception.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the brand and model of the computer you're using? It would also be useful to test the data transfer rate with the USB devices to see if you're moving at the full speed available. An incorrect driver can have a USB 3.0 USB stick move at USB 1.1 speeds.

Comment: You said "even 200 MB", but that's not exactly a small file, either.  What if it's a 1 MB file?  Does it also take 5 minutes?

Comment: not it doesn't take time for 1MB

Comment: Search this site for "slow copy" and find many suggested solutions for special cases.  Basically, any write slower than the read will get buffered in system buffers, which when full can drastically slow everything down, and take minutes to flush.